# Bash script not reading from file

Tags: bash, ssh, getopts

### Purpose

This script is meant to copy one's public ssh identity file to many hosts that are listed in a file

### Problem

The script is not properly reading IP's from the file. I believe this is because it is not reading the lines of the file. When I echo out the line (IP) it is reading, it is blank.

### Code

```
#!/bin/bash
usage="Usage: $(basename "$0") [-h|-u|-i|-p|-f] -- Copys your identity key to a list of remote hosts
where:
-h Show this help text
-u Username of ssh user
-i Location of identity file (Default: /home/$USER/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)
-p Password (not secure)
-f Location of hosts file (Default: ./inventory)"

# Default location for files
CURR_DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)"
HOSTS_FILE=${CURR_DIR}/inventory
IDENT_FILE=/home/$USER/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

# required_flag=false

while getopts 'hu:i:p:f:' option; do
  case $option in
    # Help
    h) echo "$usage"; exit;;
    # Hosts file
    f) HOSTS_FILE=$OPTARG;;
    # Password
    p) PASSWORD=$OPTARG;;
    # Indentity file
    i) IDENT_FILE=$OPTARG; echo "$IDENT_FILE";;
    # Username
    u) USERNAME=$OPTARG;;
    # Missing args
    :) printf "Option -%s\n requires an argument." "-$OPTARG" >&2; echo "$usage" >&2; exit 1;;
    # Illegal option
    \?) printf "Illegal option: -%s\n" "$OPTARG" >&2; echo "$usage" >&2; exit 1;;
  esac
done

shift "$((OPTIND-1))"
#  Decrements the argument pointer so it points to next argument.
#  $1 now references the first non-option item supplied on the command-line
#+ if one exists.

# if ! $required_flag && [[ -d $1 ]]
# then
#     echo "You must specify a hosts file. -h for more help." >&2
#     exit 1
# fi

while IFS= read -r line;
do
     echo "Current IP: " "$IP"
     echo "Current Username: " "$USERNAME"
     echo "Current Identity: " "$IDENT_FILE"
     echo "Current Hosts: " "$HOSTS_FILE"
     echo "Current Password: " "$PASSWORD"
     sshpass -p "$PASSWORD" ssh-copy-id -i "$IDENT_FILE" "$USERNAME"@"$IP"
done < $HOSTS_FILE
```

### Output

```
$ ./autocopyid -u user -p password
Current IP:  
Current Username:  user
Current Identity:  /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
Current Hosts:  /home/user/inventory
Current Password:  password
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed

/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not known
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You've done a pretty good job of creating an MCVE ([MCVE]), except for one key piece — the input data.  I see nowhere in the code where you actually assign to `IP` so it isn't all that surprosing that it is empty.  Did you need to do something with the value in `line` after the `read` to set `IP`?  Should you be reading `read -r IP junk` or something similar?  Did you try debugging with `bash -x ./autocopyid -u user -p password`?  Did it show a magical assignment to `IP`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the variable `line` for anything. Assuming `$HOSTS_FILE` points to a file that contains one IP address per line, you now have the IP address in variable `line` instead of `IP` in your loop. But since you use the variable name `IP` in the body of the loop, you should use that in the read statement, too.

So try

```
while IFS= read -r IP
```

instead of

```
while IFS= read -r line
```

Comment: What a silly mistake. Changing this made it work. Thank you.